# Elastic search query scenario

Tags: elasticsearch, subquery

I am building an application which requires a location based search of hotels.

I have three Main classes

```
class Hotel {
   String name
   String latitude
   String longitude
}

class HotelResource {
   Hotel hotel
   String name

}

class HotelResourceAvailability{
  HotelResource resource

}
```

HotelResourceAvailability - holds the availability data of a hotel resource.

The query scenario,
As a user I want to search for all the hotels in a particular location which have at least one hotel resource available
and get the count of available resources for each of the hotels

Note - The hotels matching the location criteria but without any available resource should be filtered out.

I am new to elastic search and finding it difficult to decide on the approach any pointers would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three points to get you started:

1. I would keep your data model as flat as possible - Elasticsearch isn't relational so you can't easily join from one object to another.
2. Latitude and Longitude can be stored in the [geo_point](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-geo-point-type.html) type - you can then use queries to find the nearest matching hotels.
3. Is Hotel availability based on date? if so I would use [nesting](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-nested-type.html) or a [parent child](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child.html) relationship.